# How to use ajax in select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript, jquery-select2

I am working in asp.net core. I am using typescript. I am using select2.

HTML:-

```
  <select multiple="multiple" id="e1" class="js-example-basic-multiple js-states form-control js-data-example-ajax">
  </select>
```

Script:-

```
  $(".js-data-example-ajax").select2(
        {
            ajax: {
                url: '/place',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: "GET",
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data.items,
                    };
                }
            },

           });
```

css and js:-

```
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

I take the values for select2 from the controller. When using this code, the values are returned from the controller. But not bind in the select2 dropdown.

I returned the Json data from the controller.

Can anyone suggest what mistake I have done?

Version of select2 : 4.0.3

Comment: what is data is returned by controller

Comment: I returned the Json data.

Answer (score 10):

You need to map result returned by api.

https://jsfiddle.net/vg7pgbcb/1/

```
$(".js-data-example-ajax").select2(
    {
        ajax: {
            url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                    var res = data.items.map(function (item) {
                        return {id: item.id, text: item.name};
                    });
                return {
                    results: res
                };
            }
        },

       });
```

select2 expect id and text attribute to render the list

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "id": "CA",
        "text": "California"
    },
    {
        "id": "CO",
        "text": "Colarado"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Hi Asnawi, I used the above code. I get the error like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property  'map' of undefined" in the line "var res = data.items.map(function (item) ".

Comment: can u share your json data return by the api? .map only works with array